# Should WordPress Page Builders be avoided by competent hard coders?

Tags: php, wordpress, hardcode

Do WordPress Page Builders increase page load speed and as such, should these be avoided by those competent at hard coding?

Or is there something else that I am missing as the only real value, I can see with Page Builders, is that they help reduce time spent on coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code. Page builders add additional load time. Your site may also become less portable and maintainable because a bulk of the design for your site could be stored in the database. It really depends on the situation. I would assume code to be a little cleaner though.

Comment: I thought as much.  Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

Page builders add additional code which are mostly unnecessary so it means the page is heavier and therefore the speed is lower, i would recommend to always make the code by a coder, but if the page just have little content then probably a page builder cold come in handy

Comment: Thanks for your insight and 'enforcing' both what I originally thought, and the views of the 1st answer that was posted.  Can't give credit to both but there is a 'Thumbs Up!' :-)